# Insert data from multiple div into database using jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that let user add input field on demand, which like this:

```
  <form>
  *// user select a date*
  <label for="selectDate">Select a date to begin add record:</label></br>
  <input id="selectDate" type="date" name="selectDate" />

  *// let user select how many times per day*
  <select id="timesPerDay">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
  </select>
  <label for="timesPerDay">times per day</label></br>
```

*// A button to add a div per day(or more according to user select),the div has 6 input fields*

```
  <input id="addADayButton" type="button" value="Add A Day" /></br>

  <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>1st Time</th>
        <th>2nd Time</th>
        <th>3th Time</th>
        <th>4th Time</th>
        <th>Staff Name</th>
        </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="recordGroup">
     *// the new div would add here*
  </div>

  </br></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Record" /></br>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
<script>

$("#addADayButton").click(function(){

  var selectDate = $("#selectDate").val();
  var timesPerDay = $("#timesPerDay").val();

  for (i=1;i<=timesPerDay;i++){

  *// all div that added use the same class*
    var newRecordDayDiv = $(document.createElement("div")).attr("class", "insertDiv");

    newRecordDayDiv.after().html(
      "<input id='recordDate' type='text' value ='"+ selectDate + "'name='recordDate' readonly/>" +
      "<input id='firstTime' type='time' name='firstTime' />" +
      "<input id='secondTime' type='time' name='secondTime' />" +
      "<input id='thirdTime' type='time' name='thirdTime' />" +
      "<input id='fourthTime' type='time' name='fourthTime' />" +
      "<input id='staff' type='text' name='staff' />"
    );
    newRecordDayDiv.appendTo("#recordGroup");
  }

 });

</script>
```

How can I POST those data to php for insert database  using AJAX? 
I've tried approach around jquery for each div class="insertDiv" but failed. 
Thank you in advance.